# Working with Dispatcher in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i want use Dispatcher in my app but this not run
my code is in here

```
 private void LoadPage()
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        TextBlock temp = new TextBlock();
                        temp.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                        temp.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
                        temp.FontSize = 32;
                        temp.Text = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                        {
                            temp.Text = temp.Text + " " + word[i];
                            temp.UpdateLayout();
                            temp.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                            if (temp.ActualHeight < 600)
                                text = text + " " + word[i];
                            else
                            {
                                pages.Add(text);
                                temp.Text = "";
                                text = "";
                            }
                        }
                        if (text != "")
                            pages.Add(text);
                    });
        }
```

and for run this i use this code

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadPage));
                t.Start();

                while (pages.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (!t.IsAlive)
                        break;
                }
```

but always after a second break from while loop 
but without Thread and Dispatcher  my app work good and don't has any problem
where i mack mistake? i don't know :(

Answer (score 1):

how your app now works

```
UI Thread       | Second thread
====================================   
create and run  |
thread          |
---------------------------------------
waiting         | shedule your dispatcher code 
                | for executing on ui thread
------------------------------------------              
waiting         | finishing (t.IsAlive now is true)
------------------------------------------
waiting count=0 |
....
waiting count=0 |
....            |
(until End      |
of the World)   |
```

Lambda, passed to Dispatcher, never executed.

the problem is that Dispatcher doesn`t execute code in parallel, it shedules code for executing on UI thread, so it will be executed only after current UI thread task finishes (in your case it's a while loop).

Because in most cases tasks are small, it creates an illusion of parallel work, but it simply a queue of delegates, executed one by one.

To know how ti fix it I need to know what exatly you want to achieve, because I don`t understand the whole idea with this code.
Why you can't put your dispatcher code instead of thread and waiting loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really make much sense. You are starting a thread and then instantly marshalling back to the UI thread. It doesn't look like any of your code can be executed outside of the UI thread so it isn't clear what you are trying to achieve starting a new one.

I suspect you are also a little confused about how threads work. Your code may well start executing the while loop before your thread has even started - i.e. it could easily call `t.Start()` and then enter the while loop before `LoadPage` is called.